# Retry settings for subscriber in pubsub/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-gcp

I have a spring service subcribing for messages from a topic in the google cloud pubsub (pulling).

I have tried to set those configuration in my profile config. like this to manage retries of messages:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gcp:
      pubsub:
        subscriber:
          retry:
            max-attempts: 2
            retry-delay-multiplier: 5
            initial-retry-delay-seconds: 1
            max-retry-delay-seconds: 10
            jittered: false
```

The problem that i receive all messages all the time and it's not deleted after 2 retries like my configuration.

I tried with `nack()` message but it's not working

Comment: If you don't want the messages to be redelivered, you need to `ack()` them.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Pull subscription Doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#pull-subscription), you'll need to ack() the messages you receive using the returned ack ID so that the messages in the subscription will go away, or it will stay in the queue for up to [7 days](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery) and get deleted then.